# I would like to redirect current page id to another page id

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect http://www.example.com/products.php?id=WIZ page to http://www.example.com/newpage.php?nwmd=WIZ

I tried many combination of this issue, but it's didn't work! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/products.php?id=WIZ$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/newpage.php?nwmd=WIZ/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ /newpage.php?nwmd=%1 [R=302,L,NC]
```